# BASH - getopts regular expression in OPTARG

Tags: bash, glob, quotes, getopts

I need a get regular expression from argument with getopts

```
./function -i "d*"
```

```
while getopts 'i:n' opt; do
  # check -i and -n arg
    case "$opt" in
      i)
        i=true
        pattern=$OPTARG;;
    esac
  done
echo $pattern
```

Output is `darProVas dirgraf-copy dirgraf-my`: a list of files starting with `d`.
I need this output: `d*`.

Answer (score 5):

`$pattern` is *set* correctly. Make sure to quote it whenever it's *expanded* to inhibit glob expansion. Unquoted variables are subject to word splitting and glob expansion, which are almost always undesirable.

```
echo "$pattern"
```

Comment: Except when you actually want to use it as a pattern. Then leave if unquoted: `if [[ $somevar =~ $pattern ]]; then ...`